# Custom UI Wix bootstrapper download and install .NET

Tags: .net, wix, burn

I am building my custom UI bootstrapper based on Wix toolset v3.8. However, I encountered an issue with download and install .NET 4.5. Here is my Chain:

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Redist"/>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\DummyInstaller\bin\Debug\DummyInstaller.msi" Id="DummyInstallationPackageId" Visible="yes"/>
</Chain>
```

If I use default UI, the bootstrapper can download and install .NET 4.5.1 before install my DummyInstaller. But with my custom UI, the bootstrapper cannot download and install .NET 4.5.1. In my UI, when install button click, the following command is executed:

```
Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install);
```

I also write a log file when **CacheAcquireBegin**, **CacheAcquireComplete** and **CacheAcquireProgress** events fired, but nothing occurs. Please tell me what I did wrong.

Hope this make sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "the bootstrapper cannot download and install .NET 4.5.1" so what actually happens? It installs DummyInstaller and not .NET 4.5.1? No errors?

Comment: The DummyInstaller is not installed also. Without download and install .NET 4.5.1 (<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Redist"/>), my custom Bootstrapper Application can work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to fix my problem:

- Add handler for **ResolveSource** event.
- When ResolveSource event fired, if DownloadSource is not empty, set **e.result** to **Result.Download**

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `Detect`, then `Plan`, then `Apply`.  Check out this blog: https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/